# Error when creating new Case: One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer

Tags: civicase, civirules

I have set up some new Case types and it was all working fine until a user tried to create a case and got the above error, this is happening for all case types now and seems to be being generated by Civirules code.

The only thing I can think of which I have changed recently is I deleted some activity types (through CiviCRM's user interface) and some were likely included in some Case types as sequences or timelines. None of the deleted activity types are included on active Case types that I'm using now but could that be the reason?

Do I need to track down the tables where activity types are linked to cases and get delete rows which are orphaned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what was actually causing this but it has been resolved by updating Civirules.

Comment: If it happens again, the url itself will give a clue as to which parameter is invalid. You'll see something like ?id=&cid=123, and the one that doesn't have a value to the right of the = is the culprit. Can also check logs (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/dev-tools/debugging/#viewing-log-files) which might have more clues.